# Intellij repackage dependencies in jarfile?

Tags: eclipse, jar, intellij-idea

I am a big fan of jetbrains products, and am an intellij (community edition) user for all my java development. However there is one feature from eclipse that I REALLY miss. In eclipse, if I had a bunch of jarfile dependencies, I could repackage them in my runnable jar file so all dependencies were contained in one jar file.

I can not find anything that will get this done in intellij, so I am forced to export my projects to eclipse format from intellij, fix the project configuration in eclipse (since intellij doesnt do such a great job on the export) and then build my jarfiles from eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the build artifact component of IntelliJ?  It allows you to define a JAR build artifact (executable or non-executable) that can include the dependencies either extracted within the target Jar or as a link within the Jar's Manifest file.  See this blog entry for the details:  http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

Comment: WOW. Somehow I never noticed the "From module with dependencies" options rather and an empty jarfile. Thanks a bunch, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Any idea what I could be doing wrong. When I follow the links instructions the dependency libraries are not included in hte final jar.